# LWC Open Source for Java (SpringBoot)

Tags: lightning-web-components

As we aware that LWC open source is available and we can make applications in NodeJs easily.
But I am worndering if this open source framework can be used with SpringBoot (Java) as well?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

LWC is 100% client-side. The server is only there to serve files to the client. Since they were already using Node, it makes sense to use Node for the server as well. That said, you can use whatever you want for the server-side technology, as long as it can respond to HTTP GET requests.

Comment: Further question:
So what is best suggestion as per modern web technology. Suppose I made my server side things on SpringBoot using REST API and host it on heroku as subdomain server like api.ibirds.com

And then I use client project on LWC NodeJS application and host it on same heroku server on different subdomain like app.ibirds.com

Is that how recent applications works?

In this case, how we will manage sessions on client side? Showing some pages on or not or logout or not?

Also, will it not slow compare to all code at same server?

Comment: @AslamBari It's hard to answer this in a comment (perhaps ask a new question?), but yes, LWC is meant to have a separate API server (eg. SpringBoot). You just need to set up CORS access as appropriate, and it'd be easy to call the API server for data you need. Using multiple domains is common and does not particularly cause slowdowns on clients.